# Ignore whitespace in Xtext rule

Tags: grammar, xtext

I have the following rule:

```
ASTMin:
    MinKeyword '(' expression=ASTSimple ')';

MinKeyword: 'min';
```

For an expression like `min (4)` the parser creates the error message:

> extraneous input ' ' expecting '('

Where can I disable the whitespace behaviour?

Comment: have a look at the hidden clauses of your dsl/rules. and make sure you dont have keywords containing ' '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve it just add the terminal rule "WS"  in hidden in the top of your grammar as following:

```
grammar org.your.Dsl hidden(WS, ML_COMMENT, SL_COMMENT)
```

If you are using the Xtext Terminals grammar :

```
grammar org.your.Dsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals hidden(WS, ML_COMMENT, SL_COMMENT)
```